# Laravel dd() or dump(), but only with essential data?

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

I'm writing tests in PhpStorm. So when I `dd(...)` something ( or `->dump()` it), then it doesn't automatically 'fold' up the dumped content, like in the browser. Therefore it takes longer to find the lines I'm looking for, when debugging tests (which is all the time).

How do I make a debugging-function that leaves out lines where I've put four slashes (`////`) in the end? ... Or does something like this already exist?

```
App\Team {#1631
  #table: "teams"
  #fillable: array:7 [       ////
    0 => "id"                ////
    1 => "created_at"        ////
    2 => "updated_at"        ////
    3 => "deleted_at"        ////
    4 => "name"              ////
    5 => "sport_id"          ////
    6 => "type"              ////
  ]                          ////
  #connection: "sqlite"      ////
  #primaryKey: "id"          ////
  #keyType: "int"            ////
  +incrementing: true        ////
  #with: []                  ////
  #withCount: []             ////
  #perPage: 15               ////
  +exists: true              ////
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false ////
  #attributes: array:7 [
    "id" => "1"
    "created_at" => "2020-07-28 21:36:40"
    "updated_at" => "2020-07-28 21:36:40"
    "name" => "Test team name"
    "sport_id" => null
    "type" => "team"
    "deleted_at" => null
  ]
  #original: array:10 [      ////
    "id" => "1"              ////
    "created_at" => "2020-07-28 21:36:40"        ////
    "updated_at" => "2020-07-28 21:36:40"        ////
    "name" => "Test team name"                   ////
    "sport_id" => null       ////
    "type" => "team"         ////
    "deleted_at" => null     ////
    "pivot_user_id" => "4"   ////
    "pivot_team_id" => "1"   ////
    "pivot_role_id" => "6"   ////
  ]
  #changes: []               ////
  #casts: []                 ////
  #classCastCache: []        ////
  #dates: array:1 [          ////
    0 => "deleted_at"        ////
  ]                          ////
  #dateFormat: null          ////
  #appends: []               ////
  #dispatchesEvents: []      ////
  #observables: []           ////
  #relations: array:1 [
    "pivot" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#52
      +incrementing: false   ////
      #guarded: []           ////
      #connection: "sqlite"  ////
      #table: "role_team_user"
      #primaryKey: "id"      ////
      #keyType: "int"        ////
      #with: []              ////
      #withCount: []         ////
      #perPage: 15           ////
      +exists: true          ////
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:3 [ 
        "user_id" => "4"
        "team_id" => "1"
        "role_id" => "6"
      ]
      #original: array:3 [        ////
        "user_id" => "4"          ////
        "team_id" => "1"          ////
        "role_id" => "6"          ////
      ]                           ////
      #changes: []                ////
      #casts: []                  ////
      #classCastCache: []         ////
      #dates: []                  ////
      #dateFormat: null           ////
      #appends: []                ////
      #dispatchesEvents: []       ////
      #observables: []            ////
      #relations: []              ////
      #touches: []                ////
      +timestamps: false          ////
      #hidden: []                 ////
      #visible: []                ////
      #fillable: []               ////
      +pivotParent: App\User {#56
        #fillable: array:7 [
          0 => "name"
          1 => "email"
          2 => "password"
...
...
...
```

Ideally (in my head), I would add a debugging function somewhere, that extends `dd()`, that is called `ddd()`, that I can customize for when writing tests. But I'm open for suggestions that achieves anything in the same ballpark.

Comment: `dd($model->toArray())` will display a more concise list of attributes, but might be missing some things depending on your model `hidden`, `visible` and `appends` attributes (those control what is visible/included when a model is cast from Model > Array or JSON, etc)

Comment: Have you considered using an actual debugger extension (e.g. Xdebug) and use IDE's debugger functionality? You can inspect variables there / put only desired elements into watches panel etc. https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/debugging/and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-with-phpstorm-ultimate-guide.html

Comment: Thanks for weighing in, @LazyOne . By the way, - your first link gives a 404. I've just spent 2 hours trying to set it Xdebug, without success. It's super-smart, if it works. But getting it set up is just quite the project. So I was hoping for something more light weight.

Comment: @Zeth *"By the way, - your first link gives a 404"* That's because I did not put the space between the link and the next word "and". The correct link is https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/debugging/ . Configuring Xdebug might be a task indeed if you're not aware of how it works (and therefore cando wrong things), especially if it's some Docker container (network related nuances). For local setup -- it's not really an issue (at very least in my practice) .. but there always might be some PHP/network nuances that inexperienced person often ignores.

Comment: @Zeth I suggest grabbing some tutorial for your OS/environment and follow it. If you have issues -- post it as a separate question with all the details (your setup/versions/config made thus far/screenshots with logs etc).

Comment: I've looked into several tutorials, - but I haven't come across any that I can follow fra start to finish. I keep hitting roadblocks, like:  —Unable to start the local Laravel server, 
 — breakpoints not firing or stopping execution of the code (not even with `xdebug_break()`). Every time I think I get past one thing, two other problems occurs. There are so many moving parts, - even for my local environment (the browser extension, the php.ini-file and it's settings, setting it up in the PhpStorm). ... Therefore I think I'm going back to 'just looking for a better debugging function'. :-)